# Grouping numbers with sed: underscore doesn't work to me

Tags: sed, number-formatting

I'm trying to group digits; The problem arises only when using the underscore character:

```
$ echo "12345678912345678901234567890" | sed ':a;s/\B[0-9]\{3\}\($\|_\)/_&/;ta'
```

While using other characters the work is done:

```
$ echo "12345678912345678901234567890" | sed ':a;s/\B[0-9]\{3\}\($\|-\)/-&/;ta'
```

Also:

```
$ echo "12345678912345678901234567890" | sed ':a;s/\B[0-9]\{3\}\($\|:\)/:&/;ta'
```

...and so on. I've tried to scape the underscore, but it just does the same.

Comment: Please add your expected output

Comment: `\B` is the negated version of `\b`, word boundary. `Word` includes alphanumeric characters and an underscore character. Therefore `\B` matches the gap between digits as well as the gap between a digit and an underscore.

Comment: I knew the meaning of \B, but it seems I'd not noticed the problem it causes... it is an infinite loop, isn't it?

Comment: Rather than applying the `ta` command, duplicate the substitution and observe the result. N.B. the `goto` may be infinite and will never return. The `--debug` option in GNU sed also may enlighten piped through to less. `sed '...' file --debug | less`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/(.*[0-9])([0-9]{3})/\1_\2/;ta' file
```

Use greed (`.*`) to invoke back tracking, then look for 4 consecutive digits and insert the underscore between the first and the second, repeat.